# SCULPTING - Blender 2.8 "emulate 3 button mouse" disables ALT+LMB

Tags: sculpting

Im using a graphics tablet, therefore I have "Emulate 3 button mouse" enabled in the preferences.

However if I want to sculpt on multiple objects at the same time, I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>  to change between objects.
Its pretty lame to go back to object mode and set another object into sculpt mode for each change I need to make.

Maybe there's a workaround that you guys can help me with.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by remapping the 3D view global <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>

Go to *Blender Preferences -> Keymap -> 3D View -> 3D View (Global)* and Scroll down to find a Select keymap box that has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> as keymap (it should be a few lines above the Box Select keymap).

Change the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> instead.

Solved the issue for now. Not sure if this keymap was important for any other workspaces, but skimmed through the global keymap sections and could not spot one in any of the other sections.